# For below DOM code I want to get date string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
<h5 class="val ng-binding">
     Machine states
     <div class="dashboard-arrow fa fa-arrow-right"></div>                          
     July 9, 03:24 To July 9, 11:24
</h5>
```

I have tried the locator
`//h5[normalize-space(text())='Machine states']` but I'm not getting all text inside h5 tag how should I get it? what I am missing?

Comment: Please put what you've tried in the post

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: i want to get all text within <h5> tag

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to use [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) [XPath Function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   //h5[contains(text(),'Machine states')]
   ```
2. If you want to get all the text which is inside the [`<h5>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp) - go for [`innerText` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

   ```
   driver.findElementByXPath("//h5[contains(text(),'Machine states')]").getAttribute("innerText")
   ```

Demo:

[image]